# Can't take filename from Apache logs

Tags: bash, apache, parsing, logging, get

I have an owncloud seted up myself.
Need to log for the downloads files by users.
I made the bash script which greps Apache logs and pus it to the file.
Example of line in file

```
/var/log/httpd/ssl_access_log-20200621-46.63.46.133 - - [18/Jun/2020:13:07:33 +0000] "GET /ocs/v2.php/apps/files_sharing/api/v1/shares?format=json&path=%2FHJC%2FMaster-Schedule%20Draft%20for%20SOP%20of%20HJC%20(10.10.2019).xlsx&shared_with_me=true HTTP/1.1" 200 108
```

How I can get file name "Master-Schedule Draft for SOP of HJC (10.10.2019).xlsx" ???

Answer (score 0):

OK. Finally I found decision by using 'sed'

```
sed 's@+@ @g;s@%@\\x@g' <my-log-file> | xargs -0 printf "%b" > <result-file>
```

It decoded URL, so all that remains to be done - get the 'path' value